# iOS Image scroller animation behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiscrollview, behavior

I'm building an image slider/scroll component.
So far i've used UIScrollView with paging turned on,
every view has it's own image and all works just fine :)

But...when an image "slide away" from the main view,
it doesn't fade nicely like it should (like the default behaviour),
it just disappears.

How can I change the scrollview animation behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Without code and image/video it is impossible to understand what you are doing. 
Someone can answer to you generic question with a generic "improve it" :-). Insert more information, so we can help you

Comment: Thanks for your comment Marco Pace :)
I understand completely what you say, but i really don't know
what code to show, I'm talking about the BASIC/DEFAULT
animation of a UIScrollView, it's speed, ease-in/out...
Can i control it's behaviour?